# GO Lang Web Application- Auto Compile and Reload

Tags: go

Created basic web app and it is running on localhost:8080, I have to restart the server on each file change.
File changes take affect Ctrl +c (terminate program)and run again go program  `go run hello.go`.

We do not want to terminate program of each file changes. If we do any changes and refresh browser new change take affect like PHP language

EX

First Program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func helloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", helloWorld)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Second Program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func helloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Happy Coding")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", helloWorld)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that Go & PHP are not the same at all. Go is a statically-typed, *COMPILED* language -- where PHP is a dynamically-typed, *INTERPRETED* language.

So using some special third party solution like the one mentioned in the comment above by @AyushGupta is probably your best bet. What you described in your question is the workflow when building services with Go. You compile a binary, run it & repeat when you make changes.